# Will mvc.net async methods call completed if an exception is thrown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a traditional mvc.net async method, under what circumstances will the Completed method be called if an exception is throw in the main method?

```
public void BlahAysnc()
{
     throw ApplicationException("blah");
}

public ActionResult BlahCompleted()
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Will BlahCompleted() be called?  If not, what will happen to the exception?  Will the caller receive an error code?  Does it matter whether `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment()` has been called?

Comment: Whatever answer you will get, nothing better than trying it yourself.

Comment: @RacilHilan, this is just [how those old async methods (in a controller derived from AsyncController)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) work: when you decrement OutstandingOperations then a method with the same prefix, but ending in "Completed" will be called.

Comment: @AmrEglarhy: by posting it here I allow others to benefit from the answer.  And save myself some time (hopefully).

Comment: I see. You should mention that in your question, not a comment. Is there a reason you're using the old methods? Can you not upgrade to MVC 4.5 or later and use the new way? Anyway, to answer your question, it depends on where the exception is thrown and how it is handled (with `try..catch`). In the way you wrote it in the question, I think the answer is NO, the `BlahCompleted()` will not be called, the exception will bubble up to an app exception and cannot easily be caught, and the caller (the web browser) will receive an HTTP status code 500 (server error).